# how to get all the connected addresess from Metamask?

Tags: web3js, metamask, ethers.js

I'm trying to get all the connected addresses from metamask to my dApp. I know I CAN'T get any non-connected address to my dapp, but now that I've connected 3 of them, when I do provider.listAccounts() it just returns 1

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Metamask Documentation](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html#eth-requestaccounts) :

The eth_request_requestAccounts rpc returns :

> Returns a Promise that resolves to an array of a single Ethereum
> address string.

If I'm not wrong, the address returned is the user selected address, not to be confused with a list of connected addresses.

This is a design choice of Metamask to secure users.